# Is there a "balanced knapsacks" problem with a known result?

Tags: combinatorics

You're going on a trip with some friends and want to share the load of the camping gear as evenly as possible. Each of you is equally strong, and each of your knapsacks is identical. Can the fairest distribution of the load be obtained without trying the brute-force approach of every possible combination?

More formally, given:

- $n$ knapsacks of equal weight capacity $c$
- a set $S$ of packages of arbitrary weights $\{w_1, w_2, ..., w_k\}$ with $\forall i : w_i \leq c, \sum_{i} w_i \leq nc$, all of which are to be put into the knapsacks

then we want to minimize the difference between the weight of the heaviest knapsack and the weight of the lightest knapsack.

Does this problem have a name and a known strategy for minimizing the stated difference? It seems NP-hard, at least.

Comment: Shouldn't we also assume that the sum of all $w_i$ is less than or equal to $n*c$?

Comment: Yes, we should. I've updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears to be a variant of the *Multi-way Partition Problem*, with the difference being that your weights are presumably reals while (I believe) the MPP only considers integers. Of course, for the purposes of a sorting (and adding) algorithm, all reals can be approximated to any degree by appropriate multiplications of 10 of all the numbers and then truncating.

The MPP is an extension of the [Partion problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) which "is the task of deciding whether a given multiset S of positive integers can be partitioned into two subsets S1 and S2 such that the sum of the numbers in S1 equals the sum of the numbers in S2". This simpler problem is already NP-complete.

There are efficient algorithms for solving some cases of MPP, such as apparently [this one](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/IJCAI/IJCAI-09/paper/viewFile/625/705). Presumably there are others.